# why my DataClassesDataContext has no default constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a connection string defined in my web.config like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LibraryConnectionString"  connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS3;Database=Library;Integrated Security=true" />
```

Well...lI do not understand why when i drag-and-drop tables into a new DataClasses dbml it does not construct a default constructor specifying the connection string....

I only have constructor with params like:

```
public DataClassesDataContext(string connection) : 
        base(connection, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

I do need a default constructor for LinqDataSource..

Can anyone suggest a work-around?

Thanks

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a default constructor in a separate file like this:

```
partial class DataClassesDataContext
    public DataClassesDataContext()
         : this(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString) {
    }
}
```

Make sure not to call `OnCreated` twice.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i need to put this constructor there whenever i do any modification on db structure (because the dataContext is recreated)....

Comment: Put the constructor in a partial class in another file.

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1 : Remember your dbml file name and delete your dbml file.
- Step 2 : Then add a new dbml file with the same previous name to the same location (add -> add new Item -> LINQ to SQL Classes).
- Step 3 : Double click on the dbml file in the Solution Explorer.
- Step 4 : Now Drag and drop all the tables to that layout of dbml.
- Step 5 : Finally add all the associations with the tables as previously you have done.
- NO ERRORS,,,No need to make a default constructor by your own.It automatically create the constructor with out arguments if you do as i mentioned,,,and when ever you change any data it can automatically change as you need ...THANX ..PLEASE VOTE MY ANSWER